# How to get the Default browser name in mac osX using a bash script

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bash, terminal, script

I am trying to write a script that finds If the default browser is chrome.

In which file can I find store this information?

Comment: Super User is not a script writing service. However, we might be able to help you with any *specific* problems you are facing while you are writing that script. If so, you should ask about those problems, include relevant details as well as showing what you have tried yourself to answer the question before asking here, rather than asking for a general script writing service.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. What have you done till now? [Read this page](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) it will help to find quicker an answer.

Comment: Maybe can be interesting to read ["How to set default web browser via command line?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528688/set-default-web-browser-via-command-line)

Comment: See [defaultbrowser](https://github.com/kerma/defaultbrowser).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling   - i know it is not , but I have been looking around the web hours for a solution and did not find one, and I believe this is something that if can be answered will help other programmers.

Answer (score 1):

On Snow Leopard this can be accomplished with defaults located in /usr/bin/.
From the man page: "Defaults allows users to read, write, and delete Mac OS X user defaults from a command-line shell."

An example:
`#!/bin/bash  defaultBrowser=$(/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices | grep LSHandlerRoleAll | uniq | cut -d "\"" -f 2)    echo "default browser is: " $defaultbrowser`

Comment: On macOS Mojave I get this error: `Domain com.apple.LaunchServices does not exist`.